# WIFI not Connecting on my Samsung S Duos

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My home networks says Saved, Secured but when i open internet it says no internet connection

Answer (score 1):

First check whether its just the Wi-Fi on your phone or the LAN on your System.

There are many possibilities with the Wi-Fi not working properly.

1. Either the key is not matched with the key you configured under your modem Wi-Fi password.
2. Signal might be weak. ( if signal<=10% then some devices Wi-Fi
   connection is disabled to save power)
3. In-appropriate configuration of your modem due to which although the
   connection might be established you might not be able to browse
   thereby showing no internet connection.

   For this reason Wi-Fi is termed to have very least preference because of heavy loss of Data during the transmission or disturbance.

   Solution:-
4. If you signal is weak try to get more strength by getting near to
       you Wi-Fi or having an external hardware that could boost your
       signal strength.
5. If the key is not matched then you need to enter the appropriate the
   password as set by you.
6. If the connection is not configured then you need to check your
   manual and Configure the Wi-Fi settings properly and click forget on your old Wi-Fi network to re-configure the network on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I would reset the entire connection. Delete it from your phone and then reconnect, reenter the password, an make sure it saves it. You could have the wrong password, it could just be something simple. If this doesn't help, make sure you haven't turned your connections off, restart your phone. If that doesn't help, make sure your internet connection is up and going. Call your service provider or unplug your router and make it reboot itself then check to see if your phone will pick it up again.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing settings to static IP address. Here is a [video](http://youtu.be/VM1oysibgU0) where you will find out how to do it in ICS 4.0

Comment: While this **might** help the OP, you could improve your answer by explaining **how**.